# Exclude directory when creating tarball

Tags: tar

I am trying to exclude a directory from getting tarballed. I have tried many combinations but the `cache` directory is still getting added.

The directory I want to tarball is:

`/var/www/vhosts/latest/my.website/media/catalog/product`

The location of `cache` directory **(that I want to exclude)** is:

`/var/www/vhosts/latest/my.website/media/catalog/product/cache`

The combinations I have tried are:

```
FROM THIS DIRECTORY:

[alexl@host catalog]$ pwd
/var/www/vhosts/latest/my.website/media/catalog
```

No quotes:

`tar -czvf product.tar.gz product/ --exclude=/var/www/vhosts/latest/my.website/media/catalog/product/cache`

Single quotes:

`tar -czvf product.tar.gz product/ --exclude='/var/www/vhosts/latest/my.website/media/catalog/product/cache'`

Double quotes:

`tar -czvf product.tar.gz product/ --exclude="/var/www/vhosts/latest/my.website/media/catalog/product/cache"`

Double quotes and swapping option and directory order:

`tar -czvf product.tar.gz --exclude "/var/www/vhosts/latest/my.website/media/catalog/product/cache" product/`

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would stick to relative paths:

```
tar -czvf product.tar.gz --exclude="product/cache" product/
```

(it works for me).